# Get PAT info from .ts video on android?

Tags: android, video, media-player

I want to support .ts video on my android video player. I tried with standard media player but it can not get duration time of video. getDuration() method always returns 0. I tried with MxPlayer it also could not get duration time. However other players like DicePlayer got it(how?). I discovered that there is Program Association Table (PAT) and it keeps info about transport stream (.ts video formats) . I'm wondering is it possible to get PAT info on android.

Any help kindly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Transport streams were originally intended for live video. Live video has an unknown duration, and there for TS generally does not record its duration in the stream. Ou the players may quickly scan the entire file, or look at an outside resource (m3u8 in the case of HLS) to determine the duration. But you won't find what you are looking for in the PAT.

Comment: I have recorded example.ts video. I tried get PAT in ubuntu by "mediainfo example.ts" command, there was duration time of video and audio. However android's standard media player can not get duration time